# Characterization of integral quadratic forms representing the same numbers?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Is there a simple characterization of integral quadratic forms that represent the same numbers?  I know that if two quadratic forms are in the same $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$-orbit then they represent the same numbers - are there forms in different such orbits that represent the same sets of integers?

Thanks!

Comment: In the special case of positive definite forms that represent all positive integers see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to this question unless the dimension $n$ is $3.$ For indefinite ternaries, there are infinitely many such pairs. For positive forms, very few, and fewer still with proof. Here is a pair:
$$ x^2 + xy + y^2 + 9 z^2   $$ and
$$ x^2 + 3 y^2 + 3 y z + 3 z^2 $$
represent the same numbers. This was published in Hsia (1981) but goes all the way back to G. L. Watson's 1953 dissertation. See [TERNARY](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html) for pdf's.

You do not actually mention genus or discriminant. If these are not restricted, there are infinitely many positive pairs:
$$ A(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + B (yz + zx + xy)  $$ and
$$ A x^2 + (2A-B)y^2 + (2A+B) z^2 + 2 B zx   $$
represent the same numbers. These are positive definite when $-A < B < 2A.$ meanwhile, the discriminant of the first form in the pair is $(A+B)(2A-B)^2,$ and the proof does not use definiteness, so this gives infinitely many indefinite pairs without undue agony. We just require nonzero discriminant, otherwise the form is actually a lower degree form in disguise.

Here is the easier infinite set:
$$ C(x^2 + xy+y^2) + D z^2  $$ and
$$ C(x^2 + 3y^2) + D z^2.  $$

Kaplansky conjectured that these and pairs of regular forms gave all such examples for positive ternaries. In December 2013 I was very surprised to find about two dozen other pairs, including two examples with the pair of forms in the same genus. Here is the punchline: I cannot prove that these pairs really represent the same numbers, i can just check that they do up to a large finite bound, by computer. Kap's conjecture is in limbo.